# Real DFT Using DCT

Tags: fft, dct

In one of my projects I need to do a large number of real FFTs, so I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm. Is it possible to pre/process the N DCT in N operations to produce the real FFT - exactly opposite to the N FFT case in [Fast Cosine Transform via FFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/fast-cosine-transform-via-fft)? If so, would this be, as I expect, several times as fast as the real FFT given the use of real numbers rather than complex?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an efficient FFT routine (and there are many out there) the best and easiest approach to compute DFTs of real-valued data is to combine two real-valued signals into one complex valued signal and compute the DFT of the complex-valued signal:

$$x[n]=x_1[n]+jx_2[n]\tag{1}$$

From the DFT $X[k]$ of $(1)$ you can obtain the DFTs of the two individual signals $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ as follows:

$$X_1[k]=\frac12\left(X[k]+X^*[N-k]\right)\\
X_2[k]=\frac{1}{2j}\left(X[k]-X^*[N-k]\right)\tag{2}$$

In this way you've computed the length $N$ DFTs of two real-valued signals by one length $N$ DFT of a complex-valued signal.

In a similar manner, you can compute the length $N$ DFT of a real-valued signal by computing the length $N/2$ DFT of a complex-valued signal. This is explained in detail in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28710/time-scaling-in-dft/28712#28712).