# FFT of a $N$-length real sequence via FFT of a N/2-length complex sequence

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, real-time

I would like to optimise FFT algorithm by only using a FFT of size $N/2$ to transform a real sequence of length $N$. There are already many questions and many excellent answers on the matter ([here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30185/fft-of-a-n-length-real-sequence-via-fft-of-a-n-2-length-complex-sequence) for example).

I've been trying to follow the linked answer to implement the splitting algorithm in Matlab and I checked against the standard FFT Matlab routine. I found a shift of 1 sample in the spectrum (sine input) and a weird peak at a (seems to me) random frequency. I would really appreciate a review of my code or simply a hint to debug the problem.

As a side note, I'm trying this route because I need a memory efficient FFT for an embedded device.

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

%% Parameters
sample_rate = 50; % Hz
frequency = 10; % Hz
N = 256;
p = 1:N;
t = (p-1) / sample_rate;

f = sample_rate*(0:(N/2 -1))/N; % frequency vector


%% Generate real sequence
data = sin(2*pi*p*frequency/sample_rate);

figure();
plot(t, data);
title('Input');

%% Split even-odd
% Even indeces are odd because 
% Matlab starts indexing from 1
idx_even = 1:2:N;   
idx_odd = idx_even+1;
data_even = data(idx_even);
data_odd = data(idx_odd);
data_cpx = complex(data_even, data_odd);

%% Perform FFT of length N/2
X = fft(data_cpx, N/2);


%% Perform Butterfly
k = 0:(N/2 -1);
W = exp(-2*pi*1i*k/N);

X_even =     0.5*(X(k+1) + conj(X(N/2 - k)));
X_odd  = -1i*0.5*(X(k+1) - conj(X(N/2 - k)));
G = X_even + W .* X_odd;

%% Perform FFT of length N to check results
X_N = fft(data, N);

%% Plot
figure();
plot(f, real(X_N(1:128)));
hold on
plot(f, real(G));
title('Real');

figure();
plot(f, imag(X_N(1:128)));
hold on
plot(f, imag(G));
title('Imag');

figure();
plot(f, abs(X_N(1:128)));
hold on
plot(f, abs(G));
title('Mag');

figure();
plot(f, angle(X_N(1:128)));
hold on
plot(f, angle(G));
title('Phase');
```

Comment: `%% Split even-odd
% Even indeces are odd because 
% Matlab starts indexing from 1`  and people wonder why i get so bent outa shape with MATLAB's inability to redefine the array origin from 1 to 0 or any other integer.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson That's pretty annoying, especially when using Matlab only to develop quickly and the real work is in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Matlab Excerpt corrects your mistake. You had a problem with the DFT **length** N of the composed sequence... Note that I used a modulus operator for simplicity, you should replace it with indexing for efficiency.

```
%% Perform Butterfly

%k = 0:(N/2 -1);
%W = exp(-2*pi*1i*k/N);
%X_even =     0.5*(X(k+1) + conj(X(N/2 - k )));
%X_odd  = -1i*0.5*(X(k+1) - conj(X(N/2 - k )));
%G = X_even + W .* X_odd;

k = 0:N-1;
W = exp(-2*pi*1i*k/N);
X_even =     0.5*(X(mod(k,N/2)+1) + conj(X( mod(- k,N/2)+1 )));
X_odd  = -1i*0.5*(X(mod(k,N/2)+1) - conj(X( mod(- k,N/2)+1 )));
G = X_even + W .* X_odd;

fN = sample_rate*(0:N-1)/N;   % new frequency vector data length N...
```

Mathematically speaking, the line where you made the implementation error is the Even-Odd combination stage:

$$ X[k] = X_e^{N/2}[k] + e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k } X_o^{N/2}[k] ~~~,~~~\text{ for } k=0,1,...,N-1 $$

Where $X_e[k]$ and $X_o[k]$ are $N/2$ point DFTs of the even and odd indexed samples of the original length $N$ real sequence $x[n]$. And $X[k]$ is the N-point DFT of $x[n]$. Note that frequency index $k$ ranges through $0,1,..,N-1$. But those $X_e[k]$ and $X_o[k]$ are half length (but periodic!) sequences. Hence for $k> N/2-1$ they repeat. Remeber that DFT seqeuences are inherently periodic: $X_e[k+N/2] = X_e[k]$. In order to use the base length of those half-length periodic sequences, you can utilize the **modulus** operator:

$$ X[k] = X_e^{N/2}[(k)_{N/2}] + e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k } X_o^{N/2}[(k)_{N/2}] ~~~,~~~\text{ for } k=0,1,...,N-1 $$

where $(k)_{N/2} = \mod(k , N/2)$ is the modulus of $k$ wrt $N/2$.
Argument of every DFT sequence should circularly wrap around...