# Time Scaling Property in DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

Is there a general  Time Scaling property in DFT similar to that of Continuous time Fourier Transform? I couldn't find any when I referred some standard books.  [This question and its answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28710/time-scaling-in-dft) don't give a general approach.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I believe your question is already answered on the site, so I have closed this question as a duplicate. If your question is different, or you need more information, please edit your question and I (or other mods) can reopen it.

Comment: Hello.. I did refer the earlier thread before posting the question..But it was specific for that particular question only. I want a generalized property, which was not on the earlier one.

Comment: OK!  I've edited it to include that information and re-opened it.